# React-admin 3.0.0: Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(withRouter(WithStyles(Layout)))"

Tags: react-admin

I am trying upgrade react-admin to 3.0.0, but I am getting this error. 
I went through UPGRADE guide https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/next/UPGRADE.md but nothing worked.

My App.componentDidMount looks like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    buildGraphQLProvider({
      buildQuery,
      client,
      introspection: {
        operationNames,
      },
    }).then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));
  }
```

This line is throwing exception: `}).then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }));`

Comment: I think will need more code in order to help you.

Comment: Upgrading react-redux fixed the issue. I had 5.0.7 version.